# Código em C exibe erro "Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada)"

Tags: c

O código compila e executa normalmente até a instrução "switch".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    float mg, sp, rj, ms, produto;
    int escolha;

    printf("Digite o preço do produto: ");
    scanf("%f", &produto);

    // Impostos dos produtos nos respectivos estados
    mg = (produto * 7) / 100;
    sp = (produto * 12) / 100;
    rj = (produto * 15) / 100;
    ms = (produto * 8) / 100;

    printf("Escolha o estado de destino: \n1.Minas Gerais\n2.São 
        Paulo\n3.Rio de Janeiro\n4.Mato Grosso do Sul\n");

    scanf("%d", escolha);

    switch (escolha) {
        case '1':
            printf("Preço final do produto: %f", mg);
            break;
        case '2':
            printf("Preço final do produto: %f", sp);
            break;
        case '3':
            printf("Preço final do produto: %f", rj);
            break;
        case '4':
            printf("Preço final do produto: %f", ms);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Digite um Estado válido!!!\n");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Um detalhe que o @Lacobus corrigiu, mas que não lembro dele ter especificado na resposta dele, por ser muito detalhe. A condição do seu `case` é uma constante do tipo caracter, como o `case '1'`. Ele só vai ser direcionado para esse caso quando o valor digitado for `49`. Magia ASCII, o caracter `'1'` é um número constante, no caso `49`, assim como `'a'` seria `97`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não ignore os *warnings* do compilador!

Certamente, ao se compilar o código da pergunta, o compilador emitiu um *warning* avisando que o segundo parametro de `scanf()` não é compatível com o especificador de conversão `%d`, que espera um tipo `int*` (ponteiro para inteiro) como argumento.

A variável `escolha` não foi inicializada, fazendo com que o conteúdo dela seja indeterminado. Ao passá-la como parametro para a função `scanf()`, o compilador entendeu que esse conteúdo indeterminado se tratava de um endereço na memória, e tentou gravar nessa posição a entrada lida a partir do teclado, causando a falha de segmentação.

Substitua:

```
scanf("%d", escolha); /* WARNING! */
```

Por:

```
scanf("%d", &escolha);
```

Segue um código testado com as devidas correções e melhorias:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    float preco, produto, imposto;
    int escolha;

    printf("Digite o preço do produto: ");
    scanf("%f", &produto);

    printf("Escolha o estado de destino: \n1.Minas Gerais\n2.Sao Paulo\n3.Rio de Janeiro\n4.Mato Grosso do Sul\n");
    scanf("%d", &escolha);

    switch (escolha) {
        case 1: imposto = 7.0; break;
        case 2: imposto = 12.0; break;
        case 3: imposto = 15.0; break;
        case 4: imposto = 8.0; break;
        default: printf("Digite um estado valido!\n"); return 1;
    }

    preco = (produto * imposto) / 100.0;

    printf("Preço final do produto: R$%.02f\n", preco );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muito melhor, mas eu também precisava que o preço final fosse do produto acrescido do imposto, mas resolveu o problema, muito obrigado.

Comment: Senti falta da explicação do erro

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado: Feito!